# ¿Como eliminar un registro ya insertado en un arreglo?

Tags: javascript

Espero me puedan colaborar con su apoyo.
En esta pantalla puedo seleccionar ambas ETIQUETAS  solo 1 vez c/u y mostrar el texto de la etiqueta Parque en el INPUT TEXT.

LES MENCIONO QUE YA ESTA VALIDADO PARA QUE NO REPITA LA MISMA ETIQUETA 2 VECES EN EL INPUT TEXT, ejemplo "Parque, Parque", pero cuando obtengo los datos, es decir el Arreglo de etiquetas  seleccionadas, si AGREGA LA ETIQUETA  QUE FUE SELECCIONADA 2  VECES "{1,1}" y solo debería tenerlo 1 vez ese valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que yo hice:

```
function changeColor_1(x)
{
    array_valores2.push(x.innerHTML);
    array_ids2.push(x.id);

    var txtInput = document.getElementById('node2');
    var strValor = x.innerHTML;

    arrDatos2.pushIfNotExist(strValor, function (e) {
        return e === strValor;
    });

    txtInput.value = arrDatos2.toString();
}

out.println("<a class=\"btn desc fav w-button\" id=\"" + tipo.getCosa_id() + "\" name=\"parque\" onclick=\"javascript: changeColor_1(this)\" >" + tipo.getCosa_nom() + "</a>");

<input class="tf w-input" id="node2" maxlength="256" placeholder="Vida nocturna, el aeropuerto " type="text" required>
```

Gracias por su apoyo!

Comment: No me quedó muy claro lo que intentas hacer, si pudieras poner una imagen actual y una final para darnos una idea

Comment: Listo @Sr1871  modifique la info de la pregunta, espero haya sido mas claro.

Comment: @RicardoSauceda, ¿has probado hacer un bucle/loop de los elementos del arreglo?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave una vez que lo recorro y lo encuentro lo elimino del arreglo?

Comment: @RicardoSauceda si, la respuesta que coloqué es solo una de varias maneras que puedes usar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo para que recorras tu arreglo y elimines el elemento "repetido":

```js
var etiquetas = ["casa", "casa", "vaca", "toro"];
var buscarPor = "casa";

console.log('Estos son los elementos ANTES de buscar el elemento repetido:');
console.log(etiquetas);

for (var i = 0; i < etiquetas.length; i++) {
  if (buscarPor = etiquetas[i]) {
    etiquetas.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log('Imprimo los resultados - solo para demostrar que el elemento repetido se ha eliminado:');
console.log(etiquetas);
```

Comment: Gracias, ya solo lo debo acoplar a mi código, lo complejo sera que no tengo un buscarPor, yo debo identificarlo {1,1,2} en el arreglo (primero hago el loop), lo identifico, lo comparo y lo borro. Deseame suerte!

Comment: @RicardoSauceda, la verdad no entendí sobre que guardas "o tienes" el arreglo así: `{1, 1, 2, 4, ...}`, pero el principio sería el mismo. En todo caso, suerte. Puedes editar tu pregunta con un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Gracias, si ya lo logre (Y) (Y)